# The compiler seems to be confusing two versions of an overloaded method. Why?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, overloading

In my jsp file there is a line:

```
byte[] imageData = Base64.decodeBase64(request.getParameter("imageBase64"));
```

and eclipse complains:

> The method decodeBase64(byte[]) in the type Base64 is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

It says that the method gets a `String`, but it expects a `byte[]`.
But in the `Base64` class there are two overloaded versions of `decodeBase64`; one with argument `String`,
and one with argument `byte[]`.

I fail to see why the compiler seems to think I am calling the `byte[]`version with an incorrect `String` argument, where it should have used the `String` version without any compiler error.

Comment: Have you tried typecasting it explicitly like (String)request.getParameter("imageBase64")?

Comment: i guess it's a version thing. which version of the lib are you using?

Comment: what library do you use?

Comment: You could be using an old version of the library; one that doesn't support the `String` version.

Comment: Also make sure that `Base64` comes from the right package.

Comment: Either the Commons Codec version is < 1.4 (in case you are using that library) or your import is wrong. (The latter has happened to me :)

Comment: what library? The file starts with: page import="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Base64` class in package `org.apache.commons.codec.binary` has 2 decode methods

```
static byte[]   decodeBase64(byte[] base64Data) since beginning

static byte[]   decodeBase64(String base64String) since version 1.4.
```

I think you must be having jar prior to `commons codec 1.4` in your classpath

Hope it helps.

Comment: You found it: I am using commons-codec-1.3.jar. Thanks for clearing up this confusion. (even worse: I found out that both commons-codec-1.3.jar AND commons-codec-1.4.jar have been put in the library by one of my co-workers)